# How do you deploy a spring boot application to an EAP server?

Tags: spring-boot, jboss-eap-7

I am trying to deploy a spring boot application to an EAP 7 server. The application works fine as a standalone application using spring boot's embedded tomcat servlet, but when I try to deploy it as a WAR to EAP 7 I get the following exception:

```
14:55:11,156 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."projectName": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."projectName": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/res/StringManager
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/res/StringManager
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.<clinit>(WsWebSocketContainer.java:78)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:184)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager from [Module "deployment.projectName.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:196)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 12 more

14:55:11,156 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "projectName.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"projectName"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"projectName": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/res/StringManager
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/res/StringManager
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager from [Module \"deployment.projectName.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
14:55:11,187 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) 
14:55:11,249 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."projectName": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."projectName": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/res/StringManager
```

I've done as the [spring-boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) recommends when converting from a jar file to war.

Specifically, I've declared a dependency on spring-boot-starter-web excluding tomcat:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

I've also imported the spring-boot-dependencies pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>

                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

I also added a dependency to spring-boot-starter-undertow with a scope of provided:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I removed the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and I extended my application class with `SpringBootServletInitializer` overriding 
`protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)`

I don't understand why it is not working, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You've only included one line out of the error message that you're getting? Can you tell from the entire error why you have a dependency on StringManager?

Comment: @Kenster I added the whole error message, though it seemed that what I had previously was the main issue.

Comment: The exception appears to be a failure with undertow. Have you tried it without the undertow dependency? It looks like another embedded container, and you don't need an embedded container because jboss is providing that. We have a couple of spring-boot wars that deploy to EAP 6.4 and they don't have any embedded container. They depend on s-b-starter-web and exclude s-b-starter-tomcat.

Comment: @Kenster thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I just tried and it still gave the same error. What's weird is that I have another project that is spring-boot on eap 7 and works fine. The two aren't even that different configuration wise

Comment: In my opinion, spring boot and EAP.. yikes.. why?

Answer (score 0):

Removed undertow dependency, which didn't work at first, but then I closed eclipse and reopened and it worked. I don't really know why it worked, but it did.